# Why cannot I use std::get

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, std-ranges

I just need the first element of pair, so I write codes like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> vec { {1, 1}, {2, 7} ,{4, 5}};
for(auto&& x:vec | std::ranges::views::transform(std::get<0, size_t, size_t>)) do_somenthing(x);
```

Complile Failure:

```
/home/bigbigbige/easytools/transform.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/bigbigbige/easytools/transform.cpp:52:53: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::ranges::views::_Transform) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   52 |     for(auto&& x:vec | std::ranges::views::transform(std::get<0, size_t, size_t>)) std::cout << x << std::endl;
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems I have to write like this

```cpp
template<std::size_t I, typename T, typename U>
T const& pair_projection(const std::pair<T,U>& p){
    return std::get<I>(p);
}

std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> vec { {1, 1}, {2, 7} ,{4, 5}};
for(auto&& x:vec | std::ranges::views::transform(pair_projection<0, size_t, size_t>)) do_somenthing(x);
}
```

Comment: Why not just replace pair with a struct of your own and get the member variable you need by name? (pair has almost no semantics so it is easy too easy to misuse). std::get is also more of a compile time thing.

Comment: How should the compiler guess that std::get<0, size_t, size_t> refers to the pair overload and not say an overload for tuple? You could explicitly cast it to the right function type to help, but using a lambda is more common.

Comment: you need lambda

Answer (score 3):

> I just need the first element of pair, so I write codes like this:

There is already a utility for this in `<ranges>`, namely [`views::keys`/`views::values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/keys_view):

```
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> vec { {1, 1}, {2, 7} ,{4, 5}};
for (auto&& x:vec | std::views::keys)
  do_somenthing(x);
```

Comment: `elements<0>` may be more readable if the pair does not come from a map.

Comment: In fact `std::views::elements<N>` is the most generic form for all tuple-like types.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `std::views::keys`, `std::views::values` and `std::views::elements<N>`, you can always use adapter lambdas:

```
std::transform([](auto& x)
    {return get<0>(x);});
```

Perfect forwarding of the above would require a bit more effort:

```
[](auto&& x){
   return get<0>
         (std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
}
```

The easier method would be the adapters at the beginning on my post:

```
vec | std::views::elements<0>
```

The reason behind not being able to use `std::get` is that it is a function template considering const, volatile and r/l-valueness of its argument(8 overloads), the syntax required to properly address the corresponding function as a pointer would be insanely irreadable.
You can also create a **neibloid** template for it:

```
namespace my{
    template<std::size_t N>
    auto constexpr get = [](auto&& x)
    {return std::get<N>          
           (std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));};
};

auto r = vec |
         std::views::transform(my::get<0>);
```

This works, because `my::get<0>` is an object with no ambiguity. if a `constexper` or `concept` friendly version is required, the lambda needs a trailing return type, who eventuality duplicates the return value.